# Laravel: como recuperar a chave primária de um modelo depois de salvar ele

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

gostaria de saber se é possível recuperar o ID de um modelo no momento em que ele é salvo no banco. Estou usando o seguinte método do Eloquent:

```
$modelo = Modelo::create(['ATT1' => 'valor1', 'ATT2'=>'valor2']);
```

O modelo é salvo, porém a chave primária não é retornada na variável $modelo. Estou fazendo certo ou tem algo errado?

Comment: Como se chama a coluna da chave primária? É varchar(2) auto-increment?

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo fazer da seguinte forma, utilizando seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
$modelo = Modelo::create(['ATT1' => 'valor1', 'ATT2'=>'valor2']);

return $modelo->id;
```

se a `primary key` for de nome id ficaria assim.

Comment: Já tentei fazer dessa forma, mas ele retorna nulo. A primary key é do tipo varchar(2) e não tenho certeza se é auto increment. Isso pode estar afetando?

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que sim, faça o teste que acredito que seja exatamente isso.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Modelo` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,), seria assim que eu faria com minha primary key.

Comment: No meu caso, não sei se vai ser possível essa mudança no banco :( mas vou tentar com um outro modelo então. Obrigada!

Comment: Você pode tentar fazer um CAST no seu model, Ex: protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer' ];

Comment: E o que eu faria $casts? Vi que tem uma propriedade $keyType no modelo com default int. Tentei mudar para string, mas não resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Para eu entender seu problema melhor, sua primary key vai ser um varchar , correto ? sendo assim ela não esta sendo incrementada automaticamente , o certo seria antes de você fazer o create $modelo = Modelo::create(['ATT1' => 'valor1', 'ATT2'=>'valor2']);

, seria interessante gerar um codigo para  inserir na primary key, pois assim você conseguiria retornar o valor dela.